# Google Sheets conditional formatting to highlight row if date is today

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

Struggling with this one.
I have a sheet with columns A to GC with dates in random places. I need conditional formatting to highlight an entire row if the date in that row is today.

I've got this formula `=match(today(),$A1:$GC1)` which works on a test sheet (a blank google sheet with a date in a random place) but when applying this to the sheet I need it at, it doesn't work. Just highlights everything for some reason.

Copy of the Google sheet: [Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nZDZI_cYccIqXOHo_WpKoT2IxcI1t-aQFysP4_qnk40/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the existing values in your sheet are messing with the conditional formatting. Try using `COUNTIF` instead:

```
=COUNTIF($A1:$GC1, TODAY())
```

#### Reference:

- [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480)